# How compress thousands Drive files

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am trying to compress thousands of small files (10Kb or less). I get the files with a search. The problem is that the process take long time and reach the limit of Google App Script.

Is there any more efficient way to compress?

```
function compressMonth() {
  var month = '07';
  var year = '2017';
  var idOriginFolder = 'ABCDEfesn4342322';
  var originFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(idOriginFolder);
  var nameCompressedFile = originFolder.getName()+year+' '+month+'.zip';

  var searchString = '"'+idCarpetaOrigen+'" in parents and modifiedDate >= "'+year+'-'+month+'-01T00:00:00-03:00" and modifiedDate <= "'+year+'-'+month+'-'+'28T23:59:59-03:00"';
  var foundFiles = DriveApp.searchFiles(searchString);  
  var blobIndex = [];
  var fileBlob = null;
  while (foundFiles.hasNext()){
    fileBlob = foundFiles.next().getBlob();
    blobIndex.push(fileBlob);
  }
  var compressedFolder = Utilities.zip(blobIndex,nameCompressedFile);
  originFolder.createFile(compressedFolder);  
}
```

Comment: Compressing many small files will be slow. What is your goal of compressing all these files? It would be much more efficient to pass the content through gzip. This would leave you with one big file, but you could separate each file with special characters. This might be useful, depending what you want to do with them afterwards.

Comment: Can we ask you about the elapsed time? In your situation, which elapsed time is longer between "while loop" and "Utilities.zip()"? I think that the modification point is changed by it.

Comment: The goal is that Google Backup & Sync working correctly again. It is trying to sincronizate those folder and never ends because are thousands. I need keep that same folder because is used by an third party application.

My idea is group files by a creation month and to compress them.